# Publishing multiple productFlavors and buildTypes to Artifactory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What is the best way to publish multiple Flavor to artifactory based on buildTypes?

Basically in the project I have 3 buildsTypes (dev, stage and production) and 2 productFlavors (androidPublic and androidPrivate) and I want to publish to the Artifactory

I'm using gitlabci to build my android project and I have basically 3 major stages: build, tests (unit and func), publish. Where the **build** stage is different from the publish stage, ie when I'm in the stage of **publish** my script gradle should consider that the artifacts are already generated.

Example: I **build** dev and two packages are generated

- app-androidprivate-dev.apk

- app-androidpublic-dev.apk

I want to send the two to the artifactory on stage **Publish**.

A short example of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.12"        
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output -> 
                create("${variant.name.capitalize()}Apk", MavenPublication) {
                    groupId "app.android"
                    artifactId "app-${output.baseName}"
                    version '1.0.0'

                    artifact(output.outputFile)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'artifactory'
            url "${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/apks"
            credentials {
                username = "${ARTIFACTORY_USER}"
                password = "${ARTIFACTORY_PWD}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on command line I run:

```
# gradle publishAndroidPrivateDebugApkPublicationToArtifactoryRepository -P....
# gradle publishAndroidPublicDebugApkPublicationToArtifactoryRepository -P....
```

Comment: `publishAndroidPrivateDebugApkPublicationToArtifactoryRepository` I think it's not so good ...

Comment: So does this solution you have here work, and you're just looking for a better way? I am also setting up build variants and want to figure out how to push to artifactory